# How do I define Context for DataTables in specs2

Tags: unit-testing, scala, specs2

I'm trying to define some context so that it's executed for each row of data table (before assertion is run on each row).

I've found [this](http://code.google.com/p/specs/wiki/AdvancedSpecifications#DataTable_contexts) example but for the life of me I can't figure out how to write the full test suite.
I'd like to define context once and share it with all examples.
Here is roughly what I have:

```
class SomeSuite extends Specification with DataTables {

// TODO: define context somehow???
// val context = new Before { println("BEFORE") }

"test 1" should {
  "do something" in {
    context |
    "col1" | "col2" |
    val1   ! val2   |
    val3   ! val4   |> {
      (a, b) => //some assertion with (a, b)
    }
  }
}
}
```

I'd like to see "BEFORE" printed each time (total 2 times) before each assertion with (a, b).

I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks ;)

Thanks to Eric here is my final code. I only added 'implicit' since context is shared for many tests:

```
class SomeSuite extends Specification with DataTables {

  implicit val context = new Before { def before = println("BEFORE") }

  "test 1" should {
    "do something" in {
      "col1"  | "col2"  |
      val1    ! val2    |
      val3    ! val4    |> { (a, b) => 
        a must_== b // this is wrapped with context
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I also asked it on specs2 google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/specs2-users/evQkyO-Qoew

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easy way is to use the `apply` method of a `Context`

```
class SomeSuite extends Specification with DataTables {

  val context = new Before { def before = println("BEFORE") }

  "test 1" should {
    "do something" in {
      "col1"  | "col2"  |
      val1    ! val2    |
      val3    ! val4    |> { (a, b) => 
        context { a must_== b } 
      }
    }
  }
}
```